# new password consecutive characters is greater than 3 with old password then it should throw an error. But it giving error even if it is 3 also

Tags: java

In This we are checking if new password consecutive characters is greater than 3  with old password then it should throw an error . For this logic is below :

```
if (oldPassword != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < oldPassword.length() - PASSWORD_MAX_CONS_LENGTH +1; i++) {
        if (passwordString.indexOf(oldPassword.substring(i, i
          + PASSWORD_MAX_CONS_LENGTH)) >= 0) {
          errors.add(ERROR_PASS_CONS_PREV_PASS);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
PASSWORD_MAX_CONS_LENGTH = 3;
```

But problem is it is even throwing error if it is equal to 3. 
    Can we have any better solution for this. As this logic is little complicated :
     if (passwordString.indexOf(oldPassword.substring(i, i
              + PASSWORD_MAX_CONS_LENGTH)) >= 0)
    Can we use any regular expression to check 3 consecutive character compared with old password. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: IMHO, this kind of password rules are silly.

Comment: Are you REALLY setting `PASSWORD_MAX_CONS_LENGTH` only after the if block?

Comment: No, we are setting before only. PASSWORD_MAX_CONS_LENGTH

Answer (score 3):

The parameters of `indexOf()` are the start index and the index where you want to stop + 1. So just add one to `i + PASSWORD_MAX_CONS_LENGTH`.

Comment: I tried same thing but I got this exception : java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 12

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions would make it much more complex.  You should just increment by 1 the end index of your substring .

Comment: I tried same thing but I got this exception : java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 12

Comment: This is something you should be able to debug by yourself. I would suggest removing the + 1 from your for loop condition